# Typescript 3.5.3 Why object type `{ sub: 123 }` infer as string?

Tags: typescript

Typescript 3.5.3

`{ sub: 123 }` infer as String when pass to a function with param type `string | object`.

Example

```js
function foo(bar: string | object) {
    return 'test';
}

foo({ sub: 123 });
```

Error Message

```
error TS2326: Types of property 'sub' are incompatible.
Types of property 'sub' are incompatible.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(() => string) | undefined'.
```

I expect it infer as `object`.

Comment: Can't reproduce locally. I reproduce it in the TypeScript playground, but I think it's a playground issue.

Comment: Oddly enough, changing the version to 3.3.3 on the Playground removes the issue

Comment: And just using foo instead of sub makes it disappear too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31668) in TypeScript 3.5 which was introduced along with [(generally) improved support for excess property checking in union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-excess-property-checks-in-union-types).

The problem here is that `string` values have some deprecated [HTML wrapper methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/HTML%20wrapper%20methods) that output a version of the string surrounded by some HTML tags.  One of them is `sub`.  Watch this craziness:

```
console.log("wat".sub()); // <sub>wat</sub>
```

The new excess property checking in TS3.5 looked at `string | object` and the value `{sub: 123}` and said, "well, `string` has a `sub` property of type `()=>string`, and `object` doesn't have a known `sub` property, so we will enforce excess property checking here by making `object`'s `sub` property only accept `undefined`.  That means we need `sub` to be of type `(()=>string) | undefined`, and `123` doesn't match that.  ERROR!"

For now, you will have to work around this with some sort of type widening or assertion:

```
foo({ toFixed: 123 } as object); // workaround in TS3.5
```

---

Luckily, it looks like this bug will be [fixed in TypeScript 3.6](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31708).  The fix is, I think, to simply ignore primitive types like `string` in unions when doing excess property checking.

```
foo({ sub: 123 }); // error in TS3.5, okay in TS3.6
```

So your code will start working again.  You can expect the following to continue to fail, though:

```
function baz(bar: { sub: () => string } | object) {
  return 'test';
}

baz({ sub: 123 }); // error in TS3.5 and TS3.6
```

Okay; hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAjAhgJwFyIDeAvogD6JggC2GApjgJRECwAUIojnVCDkgCIodAM5QBAbnbF27FOkKIocAGIwAHnQAmBAIwAmAMyJijCYgD0FxAxxwciGEgAqAZUMA6AKwAaRHABrLABPRxd3DwA2WTYIBBE4ABs6D0S4AHM0AQB3LHEPERAMNEYzS2sAHkKMAD5cqAqLapqY0EhYBERsAC9MXAJFaoISxABeGsQxHCd0k3J-DAArOmhmQnZObl5+RCFRcSk2GTZ2HrRBor0jEzKrGxw7BydEN08vRCwwLReI6LYgA)